# App setting name in ARM template won't allow colon (:) character

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to get an ARM template to deploy an Azure Web App for me. The Web App should have an app setting like this:

> background:color = blue

When I validate my ARM template from Visual Studio 2017 it's OK, however, when I deploy it (from Visual Studio or an Azure DevOps Pipeline) it fails with a 400 Bad Request error saying "The parameter properties has an invalid value". Weirdly enough, when I set the app setting manually in the Azure portal it's saved without problem. Is there any way I can store this setting using my ARM template?

I tried setting the app setting in the arm template in two different ways.

Try 1:

```
{
  "name": "appsettings",
  "type": "config",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "appSettings"
  },
  "properties": {
    "background:color": "blue"
  }
}
```

Try 2:

```
{
  "name": "appsettings",
  "type": "config",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "appSettings"
  },
  "properties": {
    "backgroundColor": {
      "name": "background:color",
      "value" : "blue" 
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error that is returned when deploying the ARM template:

```
2018-09-21T13:41:31.8335539Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
2018-09-21T13:41:31.8346749Z ##[error]Details:
2018-09-21T13:41:31.8349223Z ##[error]BadRequest: {
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value."
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "51008",
        "MessageTemplate": "The parameter {0} has an invalid value.",
        "Parameters": [
          "properties"
        ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value."
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
} undefined
2018-09-21T13:41:31.8351886Z ##[error]BadRequest: {
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value."
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "51008",
        "MessageTemplate": "The parameter {0} has an invalid value.",
        "Parameters": [
          "properties"
        ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "The parameter properties has an invalid value."
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
} undefined
2018-09-21T13:41:31.8354208Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

The full ARM template looks likes this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat(resourceGroup().name, '-web')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('hostingPlanName'), '-', resourceGroup().name)]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/autoscalesettings",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "AutoScaleSettings"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "profiles": [
          {
            "name": "Default",
            "capacity": {
              "minimum": 1,
              "maximum": 2,
              "default": 1
            },
            "rules": [
              {
                "metricTrigger": {
                  "metricName": "CpuPercentage",
                  "metricResourceUri": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                  "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                  "statistic": "Average",
                  "timeWindow": "PT10M",
                  "timeAggregation": "Average",
                  "operator": "GreaterThan",
                  "threshold": 80.0
                },
                "scaleAction": {
                  "direction": "Increase",
                  "type": "ChangeCount",
                  "value": 1,
                  "cooldown": "PT10M"
                }
              },
              {
                "metricTrigger": {
                  "metricName": "CpuPercentage",
                  "metricResourceUri": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                  "timeGrain": "PT1M",
                  "statistic": "Average",
                  "timeWindow": "PT1H",
                  "timeAggregation": "Average",
                  "operator": "LessThan",
                  "threshold": 60.0
                },
                "scaleAction": {
                  "direction": "Decrease",
                  "type": "ChangeCount",
                  "value": 1,
                  "cooldown": "PT1H"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "enabled": false,
        "name": "[concat(parameters('hostingPlanName'), '-', resourceGroup().name)]",
        "targetResourceUri": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[concat('ServerErrors ', variables('webSiteName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertrules",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "ServerErrorsAlertRule"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[concat('ServerErrors ', variables('webSiteName'))]",
        "description": "[concat(variables('webSiteName'), ' has some server errors, status code 5xx.')]",
        "isEnabled": false,
        "condition": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]",
            "metricName": "Http5xx"
          },
          "operator": "GreaterThan",
          "threshold": 0.0,
          "windowSize": "PT5M"
        },
        "action": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
          "sendToServiceOwners": true,
          "customEmails": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[concat('ForbiddenRequests ', variables('webSiteName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertrules",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "ForbiddenRequestsAlertRule"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[concat('ForbiddenRequests ', variables('webSiteName'))]",
        "description": "[concat(variables('webSiteName'), ' has some requests that are forbidden, status code 403.')]",
        "isEnabled": false,
        "condition": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]",
            "metricName": "Http403"
          },
          "operator": "GreaterThan",
          "threshold": 0,
          "windowSize": "PT5M"
        },
        "action": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
          "sendToServiceOwners": true,
          "customEmails": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[concat('CPUHigh ', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertrules",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "CPUHighAlertRule"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[concat('CPUHigh ', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "description": "[concat('The average CPU is high across all the instances of ', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "isEnabled": false,
        "condition": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
            "metricName": "CpuPercentage"
          },
          "operator": "GreaterThan",
          "threshold": 90,
          "windowSize": "PT15M"
        },
        "action": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
          "sendToServiceOwners": true,
          "customEmails": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[concat('LongHttpQueue ', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertrules",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "LongHttpQueueAlertRule"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[concat('LongHttpQueue ', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "description": "[concat('The HTTP queue for the instances of ', parameters('hostingPlanName'), ' has a large number of pending requests.')]",
        "isEnabled": false,
        "condition": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
            "metricName": "HttpQueueLength"
          },
          "operator": "GreaterThan",
          "threshold": 100.0,
          "windowSize": "PT5M"
        },
        "action": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
          "sendToServiceOwners": true,
          "customEmails": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "location": "East US",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "AppInsightsComponent"
      },
      "properties": {
        "applicationId": "[variables('webSiteName')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Try using a `background[:color = blue` or `background\:color = blue`
2. If both don't work out, you can always define a variable to represent colon (:) and use that. See [this blog](https://msftplayground.com/2016/10/escape-single-quotes-within-azure-resource-template/) for approach.